# Do I need to include "in it" in the following situation?

Tags: grammar

> “The cause of the disease is not well understood. We only know that genes
>   and the environment play a major role (in it)”

Do I need the *in it* at the end of the second sentence? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra pronoun at the end is not necessary, and in fact, sounds a little awkward since it would be redundant if written as one compound sentence:

> The cause of the disease is not well understood, although we do know that genetics and environmental factors play a major role.